# I am passing an external link(site link) in url and also i decoded it?it works in windows,but not in linux?

Tags: php

I am passing an external link in url as shown below,

```
http://livedirectory/user/http://www.google.com
```

i decoded http://www.google.com it works in windows,

but in linux its not working y??

i used urlencode,utf8_encode,it works in windows

```
http://livedirectory/user/`http://www.google.com` the http://www.google.com is encoded
```

but in bluehost server,the http://www.google.com is not encoded,i dont know y,how to encode in linux server Mr.pekka....

Comment: Can we see some code, please? Also, are you saying it works on a windows server but not a linux one?

Answer (score 3):

You are not giving enough detail to give a complete answer, but speaking in general, that is not a valid URL. You need to [percent encode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent%20encoding) the second URL:

```
http://livedirectory/user/http%3a%2f%2fwww.google.com
```

in PHP, the function for that is [`urlencode()`.](http://www.php.net/urlencode)

Comment: when i use urlencode,and urldecode,http://livedirectory/user/http%3a%2f%2fwww.google.com it shows error 404

Comment: @shan if it doesn't work, it must have to do with CI's routing. I don't know that in detail, sorry... You will need to add more information to your question